# Can't login in to phpPgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, centos, phppgadmin

I have installed phpPdAdmin (5.1) using Yum on to a CentOS VPS. I have installed on the server Postgres 9.3.4 also using Yum. I am able to log in to a user account I have created using psql from terminal. However when I try and log in to phpPgAdmin it says loginFailed (also there is a red cross next to the server name on the left), I have changed the conf.d/phpPgAdmin file and added the line "Allow from all". I am at a loss, I am trying to log in to phpPgAdmin so I can start using the database system but I can't find any sites anywhere offering a solution or a troubleshooter, can anyone see my mistake or highlight common causes?

Answer (score 1):

You must be sure that the phpPgAdmin application is arriving at the PostgreSQL service (even if it is on the same server).

Check Apache HTTP or PostgreSQL logs for hints on that issue.

Commonly problems like that are solved by editing pg_hba.conf appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

It is necessary to change SELinux Boolean value.
You need to run this command:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```